# When using CTRL+F5 to run in Visual studio 2017 professional it closes the window of the previous run

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a very annoying problem (that begun after I had to format my PC)
I've installed, Visual studio 2017 professional, and developing in C++.

When I run the process using CTRL+F5, and wait for the process to finish, after the process done running, the window is still open. This is great (and not the problem)
The problem is when I run the process again, it closes the previous window (the one that finished)

If I run multiple runs together (before the first finishes), the first processes to finish will close themselves automatically, and only the last one remains open.

I'm sure there's some configuration in visual studio to fix it, but I can't find it (before the format all the processes remained open after finishing the run)

Comment: Works for me like you want it to work when using VS19

Comment: ZivS, it works both on visual studio 15 and 19

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer:
As strange as it sounds, Checking the "close the console", prevents the console from closing (tested on 2 different PCs).
But on a third PC it behaves the opposite

[image]